# Ubuntu freeze and restarts after update from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub, freeze

I was upgrading Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 via Terminator terminal, and after some time I wanted to split terminal to do some work while upgrade is working on the other part of terminal. When I split it in two parts terminal become transparent and all I could was close it (upgrade was not finished).

Now after reboot I can login to Ubuntu but I am welcomed with empty Desktop and can not move mouse around. After 10-20seconds my laptop reboots.

I managed to get into terminal using ctrl-alt-f2 and I backed up all my stuff on external drive.
I would like to fix my current problem but I do not even know where to start looking, I tried update, upgrade and all other stuff. I tried to upgrade to 22.04 again, but it says it is allready 22.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with you except I did not reboot.
I found the running process command line as:
/usr/bin/python3 -s /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-o1a81gde/jammy --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText --devel-release

By copying out the folder /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-o1a81gde with sudo, I rerun same command and found it was stuck in asking me to retry installing firefox's snapshot. With simple "skip", my upgrade seems successfully completed.
I guess there might be some progress saved by the upgrading script "jammy" and it can resume the upgrading process.
Not sure if my experience can help since you already rebooted. However, I guess if you can manage to find the folder or download this upgrader scripts again, the script "jammy" might pick up what was left in the upgrading process.

Good luck.